# What is the name of the university in this seal?

Tags: character-identification, books, seal

I was able to read the second half (大學圖書), but not the actual name of the university.

[image]

The image is cropped from a book posted [here](http://wdjy.lyedu.org.cn/Item/9873.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It reads:

> 早稻田
>   大學
>   圖書

A Japanese [Waseda University](https://www.waseda.jp/) collection.

Answer (score 0):

It is  [Waseda University](https://www.waseda.jp/top/en) in Japan.

The seal is in stylized Chinese characters: "早稻田大學圖書"

(Japanese kanji:早稲田大学図書)

(English: Waseda University book)

This seal indicated the book belong to the Waseda University library.